#  How to add a conditional limit number to a look-up field?

Tags: formula, formula-field, lookup, lookup-filter, lookup-field

I need your help/advice.

I have a contact profile that has the following custom fields:

- `Checkbox`  Manager
- `Checkbox`  Tutor
- `Lookup field`  Apprentice

**I need to work the lookup field filters so that there is a limit to the number of apprentices a tutor can have, based on the following criteria:**

- **IF Manager is checked = limit is 2**
- **ELSE = limit is 3**

At this point, I don't know if I can do that with a lookup field and I'm not seeing it or if I have to go through a formula field. Either way, if you could help me get there, it'd be soooo much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've asked a number of questions now, but have not yet accepted any answers. Accepting an answer isn't required, but it is generally part of the StackExchange culture. It gives reputation points to you (+2) and to the person that gave the answer (+15). It and upvoting (which you will need 15 rep to do) are the built-in way to say that you appreciate someone's contribution. Accepting an answer also signals to the community that you don't need any more help with the question.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, I was just testing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible, I would convert the lookup to a master-detail Apprentice -> Contact. Then I'd create a Rollup Summary on the number of Apprentices and add a validation rule on the number of Apprentices.

If you cannot convert the relationship, use a trigger or flow.

Comment: I agree that there is a data modeling issue here. "X can have many Y" means that the relationship field should be on "Y" (i.e. on Apprentice) rather than on "X". I think the best UX here would be swapping the direction of the relationship (as suggested) and making a rollup summary field (as suggested), then _additionally creating a formula field on `Apprentice` to pull the value of the rollup field from the `Contact`. This would allow you to keep the validation rule on `Apprentice` and show the error next to the relationship field  (better than putting the error on the top of the page).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain the whole thing! I do understand now.